# Rails: Render a partial form based on path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

**Currently** I have this link:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_investment_path(investment) %>
```

Which goes to the edit.html.erb view, which contains this html:

```
<div class="forms">
    <%= render 'form' %>
</div>
```

Is there a way to add a parameter on the end of 'form' so I can explicitly link to to the form_retirement from that link?

**For example, something like this:**

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_investment_path(investment, @formtype => "_retirement") %>
```

Would render:

```
<div class="forms">
    <%= render 'form{{@formtype}}' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters with

```
link_to 'Edit', edit_investment_path(investment, formtype: 'retirement')
```

And then access that in your view with

```
params[:formtype]
```

You can then if/else them

```
<% if params[:formtype] == 'retirement' %>
    <%= render 'retirement' %>
<% else %>
    <%= render 'some_thing_else' %>
<% end %>
```

Haven's used erb in a long time, using haml now, hope the syntax is correct

Comment: Thanks! I also added this to the view <div class="forms">
  <% if params[:type] == "retirement" %>
   <%= render 'form_retirement' %>
  <% else %>
   <%= render 'form' %>
  <% end %>
 </div>